# How to browse items in TFS Version Control programmatically

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I need to build an window application in VS2015 to connect the Team Foundation Server 2015. The user can select the collection from Dialog box then I will list all branches etc.. I  found the article [Browse items in TFS Version Control programmatically, reposted](http://blogs.msmvps.com/molausson/2010/10/21/browse-items-in-tfs-version-control-programmatically-reposted/) which may fit my app, but the link for download ItemBrowser doesn't work. Would someone have an example or some link can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to connect to TFS using TFS API programmatically.

You are able to use the "Browse" dialog programmatically in your own application via the following code:

```
VersionControlServer versionControlServer = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)); 
Assembly controlsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.ControlAddItemsExclude)); 
Type vcChooseItemDialogType = controlsAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.DialogChooseItem"); 
ConstructorInfo ci = vcChooseItemDialogType.GetConstructor( 
                   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
                   null, 
                   new Type[] { typeof(VersionControlServer) }, 
                   null); 
_chooseItemDialog = (Form)ci.Invoke(new object[] { versionControlServer }); 
_chooseItemDialog.ShowDialog(); 
 this.DialogResult = _chooseItemDialog.DialogResult;
```

Then you need to list all branches in the project collection, you can refer below link: [How to programmatically get information about branches in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690217/how-to-programmatically-get-information-about-branches-in-tfs) & [Get all TFS Branches programmatically in C'#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558037/get-all-tfs-branches-programmatically-in-c)

If you want to download the files and folders from TFS, just see this article: [Programmatically Downloading Files From Source Control](https://paulselles.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/team-foundation-server-api-programmatically-downloading-files-from-source-control/)

Comment: I found some article mentioned about TemProjectPicker to collect FTS. What is difference between using TeamProjectPicker and Browse dialog?

Comment: The `teamProjectPicker` only provides a dialog to select a collection of TeamFoundation projects. So you can only list projects with this class in the dialog. Details you can refer this blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/team_foundation/2010/04/20/using-the-teamprojectpicker-api-in-tfs-2010/  If you wan to list custom info such as branch, you may have to use browser dialog.