# How to get list of branches under TFS project programatically?

Tags: powershell, tfs, branching-and-merging, tfs-2015

Need to get list of branches under a Team project collection or Team project, which is needed to written in some txt or csv file. I am using TFS 2015.

Is there is some scripts available? Preferably Powershell script

Thanks in Advance,
Dinesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both REST API and Client API can achieve what you need. You can also use them in the Powershell script.

**Using Rest API**-[Get a branch](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/branches)

```
 GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/branches/{path}?api-version={version}[&includeChildren={bool}&includeParent={bool}&includeDeleted={bool}]
```

**Using Client API**

- [Get all TFS Branches programmatically in C'#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558037/get-all-tfs-branches-programmatically-in-c)
- [Displaying all branch hierarchies in TFS 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youhana/2010/10/04/displaying-all-branch-hierarchies-in-tfs-2010/)

**Using Powershell with C#**

```
# Define parameters 
$tfsCollectionUrl = New-Object System.URI("http://ditfs.cloudapp.net:8080/tfs/disample");

# Load Client Assembly 
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”); 
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”); 
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”); 
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”); 
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”);  

# Connect to tfs 
$tfsCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsCollectionUrl); 
$projectService = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.ICommonStructureService]);
$versionControl = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer]);

# Query all the projects and branches
$projects = $projectService.ListAllProjects();
$objallbranch = $versionControl.QueryRootBranchObjects("full")

foreach ($project in $projects) 
{ 
  Write-Host Finding environments for project $project.Name
   foreach ($branchObject in $objallbranch)
               {
                   if ($branchObject.Properties.RootItem.Item.ToUpper().Contains($project.Name.ToUpper()))
                   {
                       write-host $branchObject
                   }
                   }

}
```

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/mani0070/1d56fb5663e39cf09813) from GitHub